# How to send token through headers by using axios post method in react

Tags: reactjs

In my react app i am using axios to perform the REST api requests.

But it's unable to send the Authorization header with the request.

Here is my code:

This is authentication.js

```
async login(data) {
        try {
            const res = await axios.post(`'http://localhost:5000'/api/login`, data);
            this.subject.next(true);
            return res;
        } catch (error) {
            throw error;
        }
    }
```

This is login.js

```
async handleSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        try {
            const res = await auth.login(this.state.data);
            tokenService.saveToken(res.data.token);
            this.setState({});
            swal({
                title: "Good job!",
                text: "Login successfully!",
                icon: "success",
            });
        }
        catch (error) {
            swal({
                title: "incorrect or password!",
                text: "Login failed!",
                icon: "error",
            });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Axios to create an instance of it with the headers passed to it save in local storage. Then, use that instance to further make requests. In this way, you don't to include it in every request.

```
const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'https://some-domain.com/api/',
  headers: {'Authorization': bearer <TOKEN_FROM_LOCALSTORAGE>}
});
```

**Use the instance to make request**

```
instance.get("users")
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
        console.log(res.data);
      })
```

You can use this instance and customize it according to your instance so that code won't repeat. [For further reference](https://kapeli.com/cheat_sheets/Axios.docset/Contents/Resources/Documents/index)

Answer (score 0):

Store it in localstorage and then concatenate it with 'Bearer'

```
let bearer = 'Bearer ' + JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('token'));

//payload is the data which you're trying to send to the api endpoint

axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: '/api-endpoint',
    headers: {
      Authorization: bearer
    },
    data: payload
  })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => json)
    .catch(error => {
      throw error;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

check if the user is authenticated to use the Get or Post requests made by them

```
isAuthenticated() {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
  }
```

Use the token to make the post request

```
 axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: ''http://localhost:5000'/api/login',
        { headers: {"authorization" : token} }
        data: payload
        }),
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(json => json)
        .catch(error => {
          throw error;
        });
```

Handle your login

```
async handleSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        try {
            const res = await auth.login(this.state.data);
            tokenService.saveToken(res.data.token);
            this.setState({});
            swal({
                title: "Good job!",
                text: "Login successfully!",
                icon: "success",
            });
        }
        catch (error) {
            swal({
                title: "incorrect or password!",
                text: "Login failed!",
                icon: "error",
            });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't use axios interceptors like this:

```
axiosInstance.interceptors.request.use(
  config => {
    config.headers.authorization = localStorage.getItem("token");
    return config;
  },
  error => Promise.reject(error)
);
```

Or declared on https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/1383